# What will be area of shaded region, in two rectangles, where 2 vertex are common?

Tags: geometry, area, rectangles

In a figure, there are two rectangles $ABCD$ and $DEBG$, each of lengh $7\ cm$ and width $3\ cm$. The area of shaded region. in $cm^2$ is approximately ?

[image]

Options given : $12$, $10$, $8$, $4$

Comment: What have you tried?  Can an area be negative?  What is the area of each rectangle?  About how much is shaded?  Note that the figure is inaccurate because it is drawn with the rectangles longer relative to their width than is correct.

Comment: I did not say that area can be negative, i found this question in  a book, and in answer it is given that the area will be slightly more then area of rectangle, so 12, more then 10.5 (area of rectangle,) no other information was given, that's why i m asking @RossMillikan

Comment: But you have a negative sign on the $12$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here, notice that $\Delta DEK$ and $\Delta BCK$ are congruent. If we find $|DK|$, we are done. By Pythagoras Theorem, $(7-a)^2 = a^2+9 \implies a = \frac{20}{7}$. Therefore, $|DK| = 7-\frac{20}{7} = \frac{29}{7}$ and shaded area is $3 \cdot \frac{29}{7} = \frac{87}{7} \approx12$.

Comment: please explain last line ? mean 3. 29/7 ?? how  did we find the area of shaded region by this ? , i m not math student :/ thanks

Comment: Area of a parallelogram is $(length\ of\ base)\cdot (altitude\ of\ corresponding\ base)$. Here, notice that we choose $|DK|$ as the base and corresponding altitude is $|BC|$. But if we chose base as $|BK|$, then corresponding altitude would be $|DE|$.

Comment: thanks got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $DG\cap AB=\{K\}$.

Thus, since $\Delta ABD\cong\Delta GDB$, we have $\measuredangle ABD=\measuredangle GDB$, which says $DK=KB$.

Let $KB=x$.

Thus, $$3^2+(7-x)^2=x^2,$$ which gives
$$x=\frac{29}{7}$$ and the needed area it's
$$\frac{29}{7}\cdot3=\frac{87}{7}.$$